# Draft-mode in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, draft

PDFLaTeX is having `draftmode` options. It's possible in XeLaTeX. The below MWE is not working in XeLaTeX. How do increase the speed of XeLaTeX execution?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphics}
\pdfdraftmode=1
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\includegraphics{answerpanel-1}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

XeTeX does not have a draft mode. However, it compiles the PDF in two steps, first an extended DVI (XDV) is created and then converted by xdvipdfmx to PDF. The second step can be avoided by specifying option `--no-pdf`:

```
xelatex --no-pdf test
```

The command line option can neither be set or asked at TeX macro level.